# How to change 27017 default port for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Currently useing port 27017 for mongodb and working proper but
We want configure new port for security purpose.

Can you help ?

Can you able to connect 2704 port for mongodb using robomongo tools ?

[You can see screen here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl8jx.png)

Also, we have tried to changes port:2704 at mongo.conf file and after we start mongo service but can't start service.

Welcome your suggestion...

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. What is not working here ? If you have errors, please provide the whole stacktrace. Also, you should take a look to this SO documentation about "How to ask a question" : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41756508/1878022

Answer (score 0):

You should check the indentation of your config file and make sure that the file has valid JSON.
The mongodb service won't start if it's invalid JSON in the mongo.conf file.

Though You can share a dummy of your config file for better assessment.