# How to configure new port for mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am currently using port 27017 for mongodb and everything is working proper. We want to configure new port for security purpose.

Can you help me how we can configure this?

Comment: if you got answer from any of the answers please select the correct answer, else add your answer

Answer (score 8):

This way,

1. While startiing mongo pass port argument

   **mongod --port**  *your desired port*

   **mongod --port 19000**

   Start Mongo with port:

   **mongo --port**  *your desired port*

   **mongo --port 19000**

2.change the port in the **mongodb.config** file and pass the config file as input.

**port =** *Ur desired port*

Answer (score 2):

Change the /etc/mongod.conf file for persistence

change `net:` section as

```
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: <The port number you want to listen>
```

Command line option `--port <port>` can also be used but will not remain persistent and you need to specify the same every time you start Mongod

Comment: I have try this but after this my mongo db not start

Comment: Are you using the free port number ? check netstat -nalp to find the port status or try another port

Comment: net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 2704     i have set this for. after set this port using cmd display "ok"  but when we try to connect using robomongo  this port this will display error filed to connect to "43.42.215.229:2704"

Comment: Are you using localhost (127.0.0.1) or some other machine. The IP address 43.42.215.229 doesn't match with localhost. You need to change the bindIP also then.